# How do you reference a linked collection after renaming it, without losing local changes?

Tags: blend-files, linked-data, library-overrides

I frequently make use of linking collections from other blend files, so I can pose and do renders of characters without duplicating them in each project. Previously we used proxies for this, as of Blender 3.0 it's library overrides which I like even better. There's one limitation I'm unsure how to get around.

I often change the linked assets: Almost always they're automatically updated in scenes using them. But what if I rename the collection being linked? How do I tell a scene referencing the collection to look for a different name to get the same group back, without losing changes such as animation?

On that note: What can I do if I also rename the blend file being linked? How do I safely tell the scene that the name changed and get the linked assets seen again like nothing happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender won't recognize a renamed collection, you need to link it again.
Then just change the instances, and the animation will stay intact.

[image]

Comment: Yo, thanks for feedback, i should probably simplify it a bit :). And yeah, direct relinking would be nice.

Comment: Thanks. Will all library overrides remain? I'll give that a go when I get to my renaming and see how far I get.

Answer (score -1):

With the [Project Glue](https://blendermarket.com/products/project-glue) addon, you can perform renaming operations and have the users of the datablock updated automatically. I think that the library overrides should remain intact, but I haven't explicitly tried it. I'm the developer, so if it doesn't work properly, let me know!